# sparse CSR matrix into 1-dim

Tags: python, neural-network, sparse-matrix

I have been trying to reshape my matrix:

array([<320000x799928 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>' with 2929143 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>], dtype=object)

into a 1 dim matrix as I want to feed it into a neural network. None of the classic transformations work. I tried reshaping, flattening, .todense, and .toarray

Any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: What were the errors/tracebacks?

Comment: What 1d shape do you expect?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My  guess is that `toarray` is raising a memory error.  And even it worked the result would be 2d.

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'todense'

Comment: that's the error

Comment: I am trying to make it into a 1 dim array

Comment: It is a 1-dim array.  Check the `type` and `shape`.

Answer (score 2):

Something that displays as:

```
array([<320000x799928 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>' with 2929143 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>], dtype=object)
```

is a single element (shape (1,)) `numpy` array, object dtype.  The element is a sparse matrix, but the array itself is not.

Starting with a small sparse matrix `A`, I can make an array that displays like yours:

```
In [101]: arr = np.array([A])

In [102]: arr
Out[102]: 
array([<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>],
      dtype=object)

In [103]: arr.shape
Out[103]: (1,)
```

This is a 1d array already - but not numeric.

I can access that element with:

```
In [104]: arr[0]
Out[104]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [105]: print(arr[0])
  (0, 0)    1.0
  (1, 1)    1.0
  (2, 2)    1.0
```

And apply `toarray` (or `todense`) to it:

```
In [106]: arr[0].toarray()
Out[106]: 
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

`todense` will make a `np.matrix`.

Once it's a `ndarray` it can be flattened

```
In [107]: arr[0].toarray().ravel()
Out[107]: array([1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.])
```

The sparse matrix itself can be reshaped to a 1 row matrix.  But as long as it's `sparse` it has to remain 2d.

```
In [109]: arr[0].reshape(1,9)
Out[109]: 
<1x9 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [110]: arr[0].reshape(1,9).A
Out[110]: array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

`np.matrix` has a property that returns a raveled 1d array:

```
In [115]: arr[0].todense().A1
Out[115]: array([1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.])
```

### memory

But big caution about using `toarray` (or `todense`).  With those dimensions the array will be too big for most memory:

```
In [118]: 320000*799928*8/1e9
Out[118]: 2047.81568
```

It works as a sparse matrix because only a small fraction of the values are nonzero

```
In [119]: 2929143/(320000*799928)
Out[119]: 1.1442994713274194e-05
```